# Count value with 0s from two tables MySql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have 2 tables, Contact Group and Contact subscriber that we're trying to join and count like values for.  I need a value of "0" for the corresponding fields that don't have any values.  Examples of the tables are below:

```
Contact Group Table:

id | name      | Hash | 

1  | January   | asld | 
2  | February  | asld | 
3  | March     | asld | 
4  | April     | asld | 
5  | May       | asld | 

Contact Subscriber Table:

id | name            | group_id | subscribed at |  unsubscribed at |

1  | Luke Skywalker  |     1    | 20190211      |     NULL         |
1  | Darth Vader     |     2    | 20190211      |     NULL         |
1  | Tony Stark      |     1    | 20190211      |     NULL         |
1  | Bruce Wayne     |     3    | 20190211      |     NULL         |
1  | Connor MacLeod  |     5    | 20190211      |     NULL         |
```

The "id" field from the Contact Group Table matches up with the "group_id" field from the Contact Subscriber table.

Using the examples above, we're looking for the following output:

```
id | name      | Value

1  | January   | 2
2  | February  | 1
3  | March     | 1
4  | April     | 0
5  | May       | 1
```

I feel like we're close, we were able to come up with the following code shown below, which is displaying the ID and months, but we haven't been able to get the count function to work properly.  Here's what we have currently:

```
SELECT 
contact_group.id,
contact_group.name,
COALESCE(group_id, 0) AS value FROM
contact_group
LEFT JOIN
contact_subscriber ON contact_group.id = contact_subscriber.group_id;
```

This provides the following results:

```
+----+---------------+-------+
| id | name          | value |
+----+---------------+-------+
|  1 | January       |     1 |
|  1 | January       |     1 |
|  2 | February      |     2 |
|  3 | March         |     3 |
|  4 | April         |     0 |
|  5 | May           |     5 |
+----+---------------+-------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Any assistance on getting this to work would be greatly appreciated, I've been banging my head trying to figure this out now for about a week.

Comment: Is the contact group name date related of was you couldnt think better names for a group?

Comment: Syntax error, at the end.

Comment: The names for the groups are month names.  I.E. subscribers for the month of January, subscribers for the month of Feb, etc.  They don't correspond with the subscribed at date.  We're trying to get a list of how many people will begin in each month.  Regardless of the names, the logic here is what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use aggregate function `count()`

```
SELECT 
    contact_group.id    
    contact_group.name,
    count(contact_subscriber.group_id) AS value FROM
    contact_group 
    LEFT JOIN
    contact_subscriber ON contact_group.id = contact_subscriber.group_id
    group by contact_group.name, contact_group.id
```

Comment: I had to flip the GROUP BY statement, but this did seem to pull the correct results.  Thanks Zaynul!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
contact_group.id, contact_group.name, COUNT(contact_subscriber.id) AS value
FROM contact_group
LEFT JOIN contact_subscriber ON contact_group.id = contact_subscriber.group_id
GROUP BY contact_group.id, contact_group.name
```

Comment: `count(*)` will never return `0` in a GROUP BY query.

Comment: You're absolutely correct. I didn't notice that at first.  All values that should have been "0" were returned as "1"

Answer (score 0):

One method uses a subquery:

```
SELECT cg.*,
       (SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM contact_subscriber cs
        WHERE cg.id = cs.group_id 
       ) as value
FROM contact_group cg;
```

Because this can take advantage of an index on `contact_subscriber(group_id)`, it is likely to be much faster than other methods -- particularly those with `GROUP BY` in the outer query.